# Heroku rake assets:precompile failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I'm having a hard time diagnosing why the `rake assets:precompile` function is failing when pushing to heroku.
Here's an excerpt of my failure message:

```
remote:        I, [2015-09-27T23:13:38.130174 #1566]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_ece222744980130b2be8b337003ec99c/public/assets/application-c7927379441221ea1d8a9e016fe470ae6acdbe343094861d91f0dade373344d4.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " */": expected "}", was ""
remote:        (sass):7791
remote:        /tmp/build_ece222744980130b2be8b337003ec99c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1162:in `expected'
```

Obviously it is failing due to some JS syntax. I have several Javascripts that I used in conjuction with the [Signature Pad](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad) application, but only edited a few.  In an attempt to diagnose, I removed the 'suspect' edited ones and retried my push, to no avail.  I also completed the rake assets:precompile command on my local dev machine, which completed without error.

Does anyone have any advice on how I might narrow my search down?

Comment: your heroku is development or production if production then first run this in local and check it is working or not RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error.  I left out a closing } in one of my CSS statements when I added in print media type